# Remove code signature from a Mac binary

Tags: binary-analysis, binary, osx, patching, mach-o

How can I remove the code signature from a binary so that I can patch it without the binary refusing to run afterwards?

*Needless to say, I'm not the original creator of the binary, nor I have the certs that were used to sign the binary.*

Comment: if the app's name I want to remove the code signature is a two words with space between them, how should I type it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are [tools](https://github.com/steakknife/unsign) for [that](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool), as well as a `codesign` flag `--remove-signature`

First two should work the same. The `codesign` flag is undocumented and so YMMV (A user reported in a comment the `codesign` produced a corrupt executable).

You should use any of them with caution and backup the application before using them.

Comment: Would you recommend me using one of those 3 tools in particular or any of those would work exactly the same for me and my use case?

Comment: Added the question to address your questions here

Comment: `codesign --remove-signature` seems to create malformed executables, at least in some cases.

Comment: @zneak thanks for sharing your experience. Edited my answer to note that.

Answer (score 2):

Another blunt way that seemed to work for me on Catalina (note that this strips all attributes):

`xattr -cr /path/to/your/program.app`

Answer (score -1):

```
codesign --remove-signature /path/to/binaryAppName
```

Tested it on macOS 10.15.3 Catalina, works perfectly.

You can edit the hex values of the now removed code signature binaries and it will launch on macOS with out a hitch.

Comment: This answer doesn't offer any new information. The accepted answer (from 2016) already discusses the `codesign --remove-signature` approach